# Correct CakePHP model relations

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have the following logical/model setup in CakePHP and can't understand what is the correct relationship that should be in place for this setup (nor really get my head around the relations in general):

- [Model] Quiz
- [Model] Question
- [Model] QuizQuestion
- [Model] Patient
- [Model] PatientQuiz

I think it's fairly self explanatory:

- A patient can be associated with several quizzes
- A question can be associated with one quiz (currently)
- Each quiz has many questions

Thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand your problem... You want us to tell you the belongTos and hasManys (etc), you should put in your models? Have you read [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) and come up with something so we can tell where you're wrong (or right, I don't think you'll get something wrong with your understanding of the relations and how to translate it to cakephp-lingo)?

Answer (score 0):

The model associations are straightforward.

```
class Quiz extends AppModel
{
    public $hasMany = array('Question');
    public $belongsTo = array('Patient');
}

class Question extends AppModel
{
    public $belongsTo = array('Quiz');
}

class Patient extends AppModel
{
    public $hasMany = array('Quiz');
}
```

You don't need the `QuizQuestion` or `PatientQuiz` models.